# Hosting an IPython notebook with external dependencies on github

Tags: github, ipython, jupyter-notebook

[IPython notebooks](http://ipython.org/notebook.html) hosted on github can be easily viewed with [nbviewer](http://nbviewer.ipython.org/). I have a number of notebooks that I would like to host there and expose to nbviewer but some of the notebooks import a python package I developed (which can be installed via pip or easy_install) and use an external data file (~ 10 MB).

I've read that if a notebook is hosted as a gist (recommended) and requires access external data files, the data files should sit in the same gist repo as the notebook. If I understand this correctly, I would need to (re)host both the data file and the python package in the notebook's gist. That seems ok for a single gist but if there are multiple notebook gists using the same package & data, then I would need to host them separately for each gist. Plus, if there is an update to the python package, I would need to update that code in multiple gist repos.

So given this situation, is that the right/preferred way to host the notebooks on github for use with nbviewer? The other option I am considering is placing all the notebooks in a single *normal* github repo where I would only need to place the data/package once but that would lose the simplicity of having each notebook as a gist.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The nice thing about nbviewer is that it simply shares the state of the IPython notebook at the time of save. What this means is that all your plots (PNGs base64 encoded), code, html, markdown, everything that was rendered will show up. Your potential audience doesn't need access to the original data/modules when viewing gists on nbviewer.

Of course, if they need to be able to reproduce your work or add on to it, then yes they'll need access to your data/modules.